# How to read changes in excel file into vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel file which is auto generated by third party software..and its readonly file and its data constantly keep changing online.
now i want to use or read that data in my vb.net application whenever its changes take place in excel file automatically.
please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Cody's right. No question, but I'm guessing you're looking to do something along these lines.

First, you'll need to pull down a copy of that XLS file (sounds like it's online at a website somewhere). To do that, you'll need to perform a pretty normal HTTP get or use whatever API the website provides to pull the file down.

Save the file locally, then open it and read it using EXCEL AUTOMATION. Just google excel automation for loads of examples of opening a worksheet file, reading cell values, and closing the file.

There's other options too such as the OpenXML api from Microsoft to allow you to read the contents of XLSX files directly without using excel automation, so that may be a possibility. not enough in the original post to know which would work best for you.